# When implementing IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> cannot access 'Sum' function

Tags: c#, .net, class

I have a collection class which inherits from `BindingList` and I can use the `Sum` function over it such as `myList.Sum(x=>x.Quantity)`.

But when I implement the interface `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` I can't use it anymore, `x.Quantity` is not given as an option. How can I resolve this issue?

```
class item
{
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}

class items : BindingList<T>
{
}

items newItems = new items();
items.Sum(x=>x.Quantity);
```

The above code works but when I add the following code it doesn't work anymore. It says the class doesn't have a definition of `Sum`. What am I doing wrong?

```
class items : BindingList<T>, IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>
{
}
items.Sum(x=>x.?);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. Please show some code along with the error you are getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your class only inherited `BindingList<T>`, `myList.Sum(...)` was unambiguously calling `Enumerable<T>.Sum(myList, ...)` via `BindingList<T>`'s inheritance from  `Collection<T>`.

Now you have made your class directly implement `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`, it's no longer clear *which* type of `Enumerable<?>` to call `Sum` on - is `?` meant to be `T` from your `BindingList` inheritance or `SqlDataRecord` from your direct implementation?

(For some reason, my VS reports this as "does not contain a definition..." rather than as an ambiguous call.)

Thus if you want to make your call as before you have to explicitly call `myList.Sum<T>(...)`.